# Punctuation in phrase "me and me alone"

Tags: phrases, punctuation

I'm wondering if it's acceptable or advised to put a comma in the phrase "me and me alone" or not.  So is "me, and me alone" or "me and me alone" preferable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From *Digestive Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs:* by Asamoah 2016 [google books](https://Digestive%20Dictionary%20of%20Phrasal%20Verbs%20By%20Isaac%20Livingstone%20Asamoah)

> Phipps answers **to me and me alone**.

and

*St. Petersburg Times* - ‎Oct 3, 2007 - ‎Newspaper [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=yU4nAAAAIBAJ&lpg=PA40&dq=%22me%20and%20me%20alone%22&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=%22me%20and%20me%20alone%22&f=false)

> With or without impeccably trained staff, I still don't mind tucking
>   into a sumptuous dinner with **me and me alone**.

I *prefer* the phrase without a comma, but have seen it as often with than without. Others may know of grammatical rules dictating the answer to this question